# Свои таблицы БД Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Требуется: 
1. Cоздать произвольную таблицу mysql в wordpress.
2. Заполнять её посредством формы на сайте.
3. Отображать созданные пользователем записи в личном кабинете WP-Recall.

То есть по аналогии с публикациями, они по дефолту могут создаваться пользователем и отображаются в личном кабинете.

Кто мне сможет описать, как происходит:
- программный путь внесения стандартной публикации в БД
- привязка публикации к пользователю
- выборка публикаций в личном кабинете
И какие функции(php) WP при этом использует. //по типу get_post_meta() и т.п.

Либо объясните, пожалуйста, каким путём ещё можно решить данный вопрос.

Нужно каждому пользователю предоставить возможность создавать свои заявки (назовём их так)

Comment: Мне кажется, вам лучше обратиться на фриланс-сайт, т.к. просьба "объяснить как происходит" выходит за рамки стандартного ответа, т.к. этот ответ займет несколько страниц печатного текста.

Comment: А Custom Post Type не подходят для этих целей? Туда же накручиваете кастомные поля и профит.

Comment: Создавать свои таблицы в базе да ещё что бы ими пользовались другие решения (не свой плагин) - плохая идея. У ВП есть достаточно таблиц и правильных механизмов для работы с данными. Вот только нечего не понято что вообще нужно. Понятно только что нужно "нечто" выводить в личном кабинете WP-Recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@SeVlad у ВП достаточно таблиц? серьезно? 
Зачем мне в поле запись вида *a:1:{i:0;s:0:"Кредитование";}* когда мне нужно просто "Кредитование", как по вашему ВП будет это фильтровать???

В общем нашел решение, меня устроит :)
https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Answer (score 2):

Зачем писать в другую бд? Вордпресс все уже представляет для этого. Используйте произвольный тип записей, таксономии. А WP-Recall форма публикации работает с произвольными типами. Вывести их вкладкой в ЛК - вопрос простой, если вы их уже выводите в своей теме и готовый цикл у вас есть. Оформляете в шорткод и вставляете в админке в "Произвольную вкладку"

Comment: ACF, CPT - они задают произвольные поля в JSON, при больших объемах записей при поиске/фильтрации будет большая нагрузка на сервер.

Comment: @ke1evra в JSON МОГУТ (но совсем необязательно) хранится. Но как правило только составные данные. [Матчасть по ПП](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Comment: Ок. Никто вам не мешает использовать произвольные типы записей+ свою таблицу с вашим набором данных. Так делают плагины магазинов - тип записей products, а метаданные товара в своей табличке с нужными типами каждой ячейки. Но только изучите класс $wpdb и пишите на запись, чтение, свои sql запросы. И не забудьте прогонять через функции  кеширования ВП (wp_cache_add). В таблице своей заводите колонку id записи - и left join присоединяйте ее к wp_posts например